# Nginx configuration for two versions of PHP

Tags: php, nginx, refactoring, legacy-code

I'm trying to set up an nginx environment where legacy code and new MVC-style code can co-exist, so that I can gradually refactor it page by page. The legacy code needs an older version of PHP (it runs best on 5.3, but I had trouble compiling that, so I went with 5.4 and will fix anything that breaks), but it is easily distinguishable by URL, because it has literal file names like `http://sub.domain.com/search.php?category=4`, etc. instead of new style like `http://sub.domain.com/search/category/4` - the key difference is the presence of `.php`.

The new code runs fine with the following in the nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.myproject.dev;
  root /var/www/myproject/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
  }
  location ~ ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

(I will admit that I don't completely understand all that code - it came from various guides and such.)

With the help of [this great tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/run-multiple-versions-php-one-server/) I compiled and installed PHP 5.4 in its own location listening on port 9001. It works fine using a separate domain for the old code, but what I want to do is use a single domain, but call the old code if `.php` is found in the URL, and do the requisite rewrite on anything else and use the new code. I found [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/317641/nginx-multiple-document-roots-with-fastcgi) and tried incorporating its ideas in my situation like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.myproject.dev;
  root /var/www/myproject/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
  }
  location ~ ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # Anything with ".php" is directed to the old codebase
    location ~* \.php {
      root /var/www/myproject/oldcode;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
  }
}
```

But the rewrite adds `index.php` to the new code, so in the end, everything matches the `.php` test, which is not the intent. I tried putting those final four lines earlier in the file with several variations, but that didn't help (either a blank page or still only going to the old code location, depending on the details). Does someone know enough about nginx config syntax to help me rearrange it so that it does what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If your new code only uses `/index.php` and without any path_info, you could use a prefix location:

```
location ^~ /index.php { ... }
location ~* \.php { ... }
```

The first location takes precedence due to the `^~` operator. Or an exact match (which also takes precedence):

```
location = /index.php { ... }
location ~* \.php { ... }
```

Comment: Argh! I now have a bigger problem. Before trying anything else, I had to reboot my VM (the first time since I installed PHP 5.4), and now my main PHP (the one using socket) isn't working anymore! Nginx just serves up the source file as a download. It has worked fine for a year, so apparently something I did when installing version 5.4 messed with the boot procedure of the original one. Since I don't really understand sockets, I tried changing it to TCP port 9000, but that didn't help. Getting OT and sysadmin-ish - should I post on Serverfault?

Comment: @OsakaWebbie This sounds like a server fault topic. Running two versions of PHP in the same VM is certainly adventurous. Maybe the solution is two VMs.

Comment: The idea is a single domain, because I want to develop the new code gradually while continuing to run the legacy code, and the internal links need to be relative (no domain name) for portability. The two were running happily on the same server until I rebooted, so I think there is hope. In the last week there were over 3 times as many questions about nginx on SO as on Serverfault, so I tried here first, but the issue is now morphing farther away from programming...